# Homemade liquid sweetener from Stevia

Tags: substitutions, sugar, dessert, jelly, sugar-free

I am using Stevia Hermesetas. Can I make liquid sweetener from Stevia powder for diabetic dessert - sweet soup with fruits and jelly? Any requirements during cooking?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of dessert you're trying to make?  Puddings vs cakes vs cookies vs candies will all have different answers. If you are looking for this for a specific recipe, post the recipe.

Comment: Post responses here by clicking on "Add a comment" or edit your original question with the additional information.  Don't use the Answer section unless you're actually answering your own question. :)

Comment: Great!  And to clarify, are you British? I'm in the US and Jelly is Jam but from context I think you mean what we Americans call "Jell-o", a gelatin-based dessert.

Comment: @Catija Thanks. I am going to change it as I am not familiar with cell phone version and cannot find delete button :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: It seems to me that the real intent of this question is something like "will stevia dissolve like sugar to make simple syrup"?

Answer (score 4):

I buy bulk pure [Stevioside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steviol_glycoside) powder online. It's *much* cheaper to buy the pure powder that way and make your own stock solution.
I make my stock strong enough so that 1 drop equals 1 teaspoon (4g) sugar in sweetness, 3 drops per tablespoon (12g).

**For 100 ml:**

**23.5 gram Stevia powder**

**20 ml 95% ethanol**

**Bring to 100 ml with water.**

The alcohol is added both because Stevia isn't that soluble in plain water, but *is* in 20% ethanol, and as preservative. I've kept a single jar for over three years now, opening periodically; no mold, no growth problems.

I find the powder just too fiddly to work with in the kitchen; tiny scoops, or always weighing out 100 mg. Plus the pure powder likes to puff up into the air. A good strong stock solution is far easier to handle cooking-wise.

Note: bottle lasted through June 2016 at room temp, with no spoilage or degradation. So 2-3 year shelf life, at least.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to simply buy a stevia plant. It's much like mint so hard to kill, easily sourced in England (i have one in my garden which came from a local garden centre) I'm sure they must be available in America too.

The leaves are so sickly sweet its unreal. I can't stand the taste but then again I'm pretty sugar free in my diet anyway so even the slightest amount of sweetness makes me feel slightly ill (too long as a pastry chef).

Rambling aside, as I mentioned the leaves are so sweet I see no reason why infusing the leaves in water. Like you would for mint tea, wouldn't produce a very sweet water liquid.

Stevia is marketed as not containing any calories. As such it will never be a substitute for sugar in baking as apart from being sweet it holds no other reseblense to sugar. It won't for example caramelize nor can it be used as a preservative.

As far as a sugar syrup substitute you could infuse the stevia in water and thicken it with xanthan gum. Though it will never taste like caramel it may work for fruit coulis and jellys (jello).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cook with Stevia, and yes, you can mix it with water to make a liquid sweetener. The [Hermesetas website](https://www.hermesetas.com/steviasweet/glazed_cherry_cookies.php) has a few dessert recipes.

For a quicky experiment into making a liquid sweetener with Stevia, I mixed nine 1 gram packets of Stevia in the Raw with 3 TBS of water and brought it to a boil. A tsp of the liquid (into which the Stevia completely dissolved when it boiled) was just the right amount to sweeten a cup if tea.

Just for comparison sake, Stevia in the Raw contains Stevia and dextrose.

It will sweeten like sugar, but it won't "cream" like sugar, nor will it make a syrup like sugar. It should work fine to sweeten jams, jellies and gelatin desserts, but it won't have the preservative action of sugar.

The label on your product should tell you how much of the product you will need to equal the sweetness of an amount of sugar.

Comment: I'm not sure that your experiment is valid for the OP's case. Your sweetener contained both stevia and dextrose. How do you know that the sweet taste of your liquid sweetener was due to the stevia and not due to the dextrose?

Comment: @rumtscho Because most (including Hermesetas) formulations include dextrose.

Comment: But the OP says that this is for a diabetic's dessert, so they will obviously not use a dextrose containing formulation

Comment: @rumtscho My Stevia says on the label, "Suitable for people with diabetes". I'm sure that statement is FDA qualified. It's less than a gram of dextrose per "serving".

Comment: Then sorry, but the packaging makes no sense. Stopping here now, as the discussion takes us too far from cooking.

Comment: You can buy 95% Stevosides bulk powder online for cheap. No dextrose. My stock solution is 235 gram per liter Stevia in 20% ethanol (I use Everclear, but vodka would work as well). The alcohol not only prevents growth, it's required to get the Stevia in solution at that high a concentration. Sweetness-wise, the stock works out to 1 drop per teaspoon, 3 drop per tablespoon, 48 drop per cup (about 2.4 ml per 200 gram sugar equivalent).